# HTML Flex layout looks different in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, css-calc

I'm trying to get a simple flex layout to work the same in IE11 as it does in Chrome.

In Chrome it appears like this:
[image]

However in IE11 it appears like this:
[image]

Here is the code :

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: calc( 100vh - 8px);
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #222222;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

header {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

#footer {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 135px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  .sidebar {
    flex: 0;
    order: 2
  }
  .main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<body translate="no">


  <div class="wrap">


    <header>

      <div class="header-inner-left">
      </div>

      <div class="header-inner">
      </div>

    </header>

    <main class="main">


      <div class="sidebar">

      </div>



      <div class="content">


      </div>


    </main>



    <div id="footer">
      <div class='footerleft'>

      </div>
      <div class='footerright'>

      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>



  </div>

</body>
```

That shows the HTML & CSS.
Is there anyway to make this look the same.

If I set `.wrap` so it uses:

```
height: calc( 100vh -  8px );
```

Then the loading page looks correct, but I need the ability for the content to grown beyond the .wrap correctly so set `min-height: calc( 100vh -  8px );`

Is there any way to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: If you are available to use any alternate code to generate the consistent output across different browsers then you can refer to this [example](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/ZKaXGM). It is similar to your design and further you can try to modify it as per your own requirement. It may help you to avoid the issue for the IE browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea that may work for you:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.wrap {
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #222222;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

header {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 25px;
}

#footer {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 25px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 135px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header>
    <div class="header-inner-left"></div>
    <div class="header-inner"></div>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </main>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class='footerleft'></div>
    <div class='footerright'></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. This works in that it fills the screen, but setting `.wrap` to ` height: 100vh;` stop it expanding on a page that is longer. Setting it to `height: 100vh;` fixes that but stop it looking right when the content isn't longer that a single page.  Is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: Try adding this:  `body { display: flex; }, .wrap { min-height: 100vh; flex-grow: 1 }`.

Comment: Adding this seems to fix the display height issue, but aligns the page to the left of the screen, where it used to be centred.  Anyway to centre it as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `display: flex` on `.wrap`? because on https://caniuse.com/?search=calc you can find that "IE & Edge are reported to not support `calc` inside a 'flex'."

So if you use `display: block` instead, it might work on IE. In your CSS rule for `.wrap` I see that you have `flex-direction: column;`, but there are no other settings in that rule that would make a practical difference to using  `display: block`.

Comment: Hi I've tried this and it doesn't seem to help. Any ideas ?